# How to return results on a sepcific query?

Tags: database, ms-access

Basically I have a table with a product list and 2 binary fields, such as, requires signature, requires tracking.

Then I have a list of couriers, that also have those 2 boolean fields.

I want to return a list of all couriers we can use for a specific product, knowing that a product that has yes in one binary field needs a yes in the other one. But no can have a yes or no on the other table.

```
ProductNumber trackingrequired signaturerequired
123               yes                     no

CourierID trackingrequired signaturerequired
1                    yes                     yes
2                    no                       no
3                    yes                     no
4                   no                       yes
5                    yes                     no
```

Query would return 1 3 and 5:

```
ProductNumber CourierID
123              1
123              3
123              5
```

Since the signature is not required, the data on the second column is irrelevant for this case. I'm happy to change the way the data is stored if necessary. 
I am using MSAcess.

Comment: Please include sample table data.  I can't "dig" your question just based on this description.

Comment: @Francisco: I assume you mean "boolean" or "yes/no" fields. Binary fields are something very different. -- Please use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for sample data.

Comment: Yeah boolean. Will do. Just a sec

Comment: Added some sample example data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a "helper field".

```
((IIf(([tblmarketplaceshippingservices].[Tracked]="Yes" And [tblCourierServices].[Tracked]="No") Or ([tblmarketplaceshippingservices].[SignatureRequired]="Yes" And [tblCourierServices].[Signature Required]="No"),0,1))=1));
```

Then filter out the 0s. Basically the only cases that are no good, are the ones that something is yes on the first table, and no on the second one. All the other yes no combinations are good.

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough product records for a decent sample. But try:

```
SELECT Products.ProductNumber, Couriers.CourierID, Couriers.TrackingRequired, Couriers.SignatureRequired
FROM Couriers, Products
WHERE (((IIf([Products]![TrackingRequired]=-1,[Couriers]![TrackingRequired]=-1, IIf(Products!SignatureRequired=-1,[Couriers]![SignatureRequired]=-1,[Couriers]![SignatureRequired]>=-1)))));
```